# How do I return a mapped data's value given a key in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a Firebase a query that returns a set of data that I am converting to a map. I am then trying to access the value at key "postScore" but I'm receiving the error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String". I have also tried using "value(forKeyPath: )" to no avail.

```
func getAccountScore(){
        let postsRef = db.collection("posts")
        let query = postsRef.whereField("UID", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        query.getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.numberOfPosts = querySnapshot!.count
                print("number of posts: \(self.numberOfPosts)")
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)).sorted(by: >)

                    print(dataDescription["postScore"])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `document.data()` print?

Answer (score 5):

`document.data()` return type is an Optional `Dictionary` as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot.html) so you should get the `postScore` as below,

```
let postScore = document.data()?["postScore"]
print(postScore)
```

Currently you are trying to treat an `Array` of `String`(that you created using `.map{}`) as a Dictionary to get `postScore` value but compiler won't allow to use `Array` as a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are going to do with dataDescription but on first glance it looks like you are just trying to get the postScore from each post.

@Kamran's answer is terrific but here's an alternate more Firestore way; you can use `.get` to access any of the child fields in a document.

```
for doc in snapshot!.documents {
    let key = doc.documentID
    let postScore = doc.get("postScore") as? String ?? "No Score"
    print(key, postScore)
}
```

Note that I added some nil coalescing in case a document is missing postScore the app won't crash or have a nil var.